# How to parse an awk variable

Tags: awk, scripting

I'm trying to pull some information out of a log file, looking back over a specific period of time (e.g. the past hour). I've found the following awk construct that works, capturing the data as a variable:

```
myvar="$(awk '$0>=from&&$0<=to' from="$(date +%b" "%d" "%H:%M:%S -d -10minute)" to="$(date +%b" "%d" "%H:%M:%S)" /var/log/messages)"
```

I'd like to be able to get certain information from that variable, and use it to create an alarm, but I'm not sure how to do it, is it by using Grep or something else?

If anyone knows the solution, and can show me how, I'd very much appreciate it.

Here's some more detail: this is only an example. Say I look back over syslog for the past hour, saving all output as a variable with the awk construct above. Now, I want to parse out some data as the basis for sending an alerting email e.g. the keyword (or key phrase) "kdump" from "Apr 16 12:32:26 satest01 kdump: kexec: loaded kdump kernel". How would I extract that information from my variable?

Comment: It would be bettef if you show example data and what you wants to receive from it

Comment: Example of a log file entry and the desired result please.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add an example of your input and ii) an example of your desired output. We can't help you unless we know what you are parsing and how you want to parse it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.  This is only an example.  Say I look back over syslog for the past hour, saving all output as a variable with the awk construct above.  Now, I want to parse out some data as the basis for sending an alerting email e.g. the keyword (or key phrase) "kdump" from "Apr 16 12:32:26 satest01 kdump: kexec: loaded kdump kernel". How would I extract that information from my variable?

Comment: Please add that detail into your question: it is too important to be buried as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to grep the info directly out of the logfile, you can use

```
echo "${var}" | grep "kdump"
```

You could also use a pipe:

```
awk ...your_script | grep "kdump"
```

When you want to grep more words, use `grep -E`

```
awk ...your_script | grep -E "kdump|Diggy|other string"
```